# Printout Constraints and Objective Function using Gurobi C# interface

Tags: c#, gurobi

Given a model, how to printout

1. all added constraints
2. its objective function?

in C#?

Says

```
GRBVar newVar=model.AddVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.BINARY, "newvar");
model.AddConstr(newVar<=1,"newConstraint");
model.SetObjective(newVar*2,GRB.MAXIMIZE);

//Printout all constraint in the model(suppose to be newVar<=1)
//Printout model objective function (suppose to be newVar*2)
```

How do I achieve what is in the comments? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are an easy way, but what you could is to use `model.write("model.lp")` and then read the file and write it to the console afterwards.

Otherwise I think you have to construct the strings yourself by iterating trough the constraints.

You can read about how to extract the attributes from the constraints 
[here](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.0/reference-manual/node652#sec:Attributes).